# On the continued fraction of $e$

Tags: continued-fractions

The following question comes up during analysis of Padé approximants to $e^x$ (see [my related question in MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88260/pade-approximations-of-e) for more background). Recall that the continued fraction expansion of $e$ is
$$ e = [2,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,\ldots]. $$
Consider
$$ \begin{align*}
R_{k,k} &= [2,1,2,1,1,4,\ldots,1,1,2(k-1),1,1] \text{ and } \\
R_{k+1,k-1} &= [2,1,2,1,1,4,\ldots,1,1,2(k-1),1,1,k].
\end{align*} $$
Empirically, we always have
$$ |R_{k+1,k-1} - e| < |R_{k,k} - e|. $$
Can anyone explain why?

Edit: Now I can explain why. We have
$$
\frac{R_{k,k} + R_{k+1,k-1}}{2} = [2,1,2,1,1,4,\ldots,1,1,2k,1,1,2(k-1),\ldots,1,1,4,1,1,3].
$$
When $k$ is even (odd), this will differ from the continued fraction in an even (odd) position, by being too small. This means that the value is larger (smaller) than $e$. Since $R_{k,k}$ is an upper (lower) bound on $e$, and $R_{k+1,k-1}$ is a lower (upper) bound on $e$, we get what we want.

Now it remains to prove this continued fraction expansion of $(R_{k,k} + R_{k+1,k-1})/2$...

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I edited in a link to your related question on MathOverflow.

Comment: I presume you're very much aware of the [explicit expressions for the Padé approximants of $\exp\,z$](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41226/41228#41228)?

Comment: @J.M.: That's how I proved the rest of my MathOverflow question. But my estimates are not good enough to decide which of $|R_{k+1,k-1}-e|,|R_{k,k}-e|$ is bigger.

Comment: It seems that it is possible to obtain $R_{k+1,k-1}$ from $R_{k,k}$ by
applying a Bauer-Muir transformation w.r.t. a convenient sequence $\left(
w_{k}\right) _{k\geq 0}$, $w_{3k}=1/k$, $w_{3k\pm 1}=0$.

Comment: @Américo: Can you expand on this? Doesn't the Bauer-Muir transformation conserve the value of the continued fraction?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: The Bauer-Muir transformation of a c.f. is a new c.f.. It exists iff $\lambda_{k}:=1-w_{k-1}(b_{k}+w_{k})\neq 0$ for $k=1,2,\dots$. Then for $b_{k}>0$, the transformed c.f. converges for the same value. See e.g. J. Mc Laughlin, and Nancy J. Wyshinski, *[Real numbers with polynomial continued fraction expansions](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0402/0402462v2.pdf)*, arXiv, 2004, definition in section 5 and proposition 5.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: If I am right the approximants $A_{n}/B_{n}$ of the given c.f. for $
e=2+K_{j=1}^{\infty }\left( 1/b_{j}\right) $ satisfy $
A_{3k+1}/B_{3k+1}=R_{k,k}$ while the modified approximants $C_{n}/D_{n}$
satisfy $C_{3k+1}/D_{3k+1}=\left( A_{3k+1}+A_{3k}/k\right) /\left(
B_{3k+1}+B_{3k}/k\right) =R_{k+1,k-1}$. Since $b_{k}>0$, $R_{k+1,k-1}$
converges to $e$ provided that $\lambda _{k}:=1-w_{k-1}(b_{k}+w_{k})\neq 0$
for $k=1,2,\ldots $. The sequence $\left( w_{k}\right) _{k\geq 0}$ would be $%
w_{3k}=1/k$, $w_{3k\pm 1}=0$.